# Arch Linux install while on a network that requires browser-based login

Tags: linux, arch-linux, liveusb

I need to be able to log in to my dorm's internet connection using a web browser. Without doing so, I have no internet connection, and can therefore not install Arch Linux or any packages or what have you.

I have the exact same issue on both a bootable flash drive and in VirtualBox. I know it's possible to get a command line web browser, but I have no idea how I could get that running without even having Arch installed in the first place. Does anyone know how to get a command-line browser or have any otherwise creative ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have another Linux distro installed, I think the following article from the Arch wiki is what you want:

[Install from Existing Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_Existing_Linux)

You can use your existing Linux to connect to the Internet graphically and then follow the article.

Answer (score 2):

Recent Arch Linux images include the `elinks` browser, which even has basic JavaScript support.